# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of this strange density

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be independent random samples from distribution with density 
$$f(x) = \frac{\theta e^{\theta(x-\mu)}}{(1+e^{\theta(x-\mu)})^2}$$ for $x$ real, and $\mu$ from $\Bbb R$, $\theta >0$.
We are asked to find MLE of $\mu$ and $\theta$.

I tried to obtain the joint density, and took the log-likelihood. But I cannot deal with this denominator. Any hint will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It's a [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution). I don't think you can find a closed form for the MLE estimator, you will have to resort to numerical methods.

Comment: Thank you! I will go and check

Answer (score 0):

So Joint likelihood is $\theta^n e^{-\mu \theta n} \frac{e^{\theta \sum x_i}}{(1 + e^{\theta(x_1 - \mu)})^2 ... (1 + e^{\theta(x_n - \mu)})^2}$

Taking log, we have:

$\log \theta^n - \mu \theta n + \theta \sum x_i - 2 \sum \log(1 + e^{\theta (x_i - \mu)})$

I believe taking partial derivatives with respect $\mu$ and $\theta$ can get you the results.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly where I stop now. Since taking partial derivative will have to use chain rule on the last term, and it also cannot be solved when you set derivative to 0